# What is a WSDL file and how do I use it in VB6/VBA

Tags: soap, vb6, wsdl

I have just installed QAS Pro Web on a computer and I am now trying to figure out how to programmatically access the service from another computer.

So far I have worked out that the QAS ProWeb installation has opened port 2021 on my computers' firewall and is hosting a file called `proweb.wsdl` which is available through `http://x.x.x.x:2021/proweb.wsdl`. This is a rather lengthy XML file. Nmap shows that port 2021 is hosting a service called `serverexec`.

I can also go to `http://x.x.x.x:80/` to access the QAS Pro Web sample site.

[This page](http://www.qas.co.uk/systems-integrators/pro-web-tech-info.htm) on the QAS website mentions SOAP so my current thinking is that I need to perform some sort of SOAP request from VB6 presumably by building a URL string containing my request, sending this to port 2021 which will then return an object, the properties of which will contain the information I need. I can then enumerate through the the properties to get the relevant information.

To sum up, I need to know what a WSDL file is an how to use it in VB6/VBA, a general answer would be great, if somebody specifically has experience doing this with QAS that would be amazing.

I have to do this from Microsoft Access, I am mentioning VB6 as well to broaden the scope of the question as info regarding VB6 will still be helpful, I would love to do this from C# instead but it is not an option.

Am I on the right track here or not at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WSDL is "Web Services Description Language". A .WSDL file describes the web service sufficiently that a program can generate code to permit the service to be easily accessed.

The best way to use one from VB6 (and VBA, for that matter), is to create a .NET "class library" project, use "Add Service Reference", pointing to the WSDL. That will create classes which can be used to access the service.

You then create a COM interface to expose the parts of the service that you care about. By exposing this as COM, both VBA and VB6 will be able to access the service. Neither of them cares whether the COM object was created with .NET or with C++.

Comment: You could also use Microsoft's SOAP Toolkit provided for this purpose.  But it is no longer supported, was always a pain to use, and may not work on post-XP systems.  Another option is PocketSOAP but I've had trouble with it post-XP too.

Comment: We are using pocketsoap succesfully in our VB6 application (on all current OS's). It is still very much alive and the author offers excellent support through a mailing list.